# ssh-keys generation issue for dynamic-ip changing workstations for Gitolite usage

Tags: ssh-keys, gitolite, dynamic-ip

I want to use Gitolite for Git access control.

My question is on ssh keygen for dynamic IP changing workstations. So, do I need to generate ssh keys every time whenever my IP changes. This going to be tedious work for all developers as they use laptops and they need to generate keys and push to Gitolite repo.

Is there any workaround or some other solutions for this ssh public keys generation problem for Gitolite use?

Answer (score 2):

Key generation has nothing to do with IP address from the client perspective.

When you generate an SSH key-pair, for lack of a better analogy, you're generating some files which contain really long numbers which can be used to encrypt or decrypt things.  The private key is stored in .ssh/id_rsa (for an RSA key) and the public key is stored in .ssh/id_rsa.pub

You can move that key pair to any machine you wish.  You should make sure that the private key is always well protected.  The public key, you can give to anyone or copy it wherever you like.  It's public.  You can also have multiple keys on a machine, with different keys used for different hosts.  This is controlled by a .ssh/config file.  However, most users don't need that, and stick with a single key pair.

Specifically in the case of gitolite, you'll be storing the public keys of your users in the gitolite-admin/keys directory.

In any case, the fact that your laptop's IP address is changing will have no effect on your keys.